# Cannot make POST/GET request to HTTPS server with HTTP authentication through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ssl, xmlhttprequest, apache2, http-authentication

Suppose that I have two servers: Server A and Server B. Server A hosts the following page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      console.log("XML Request object created.");

      http.open("POST", 'https://serverb.com/file', true, 'user', 'pass');

      http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log("readystatechange: "+http.status+":"+http.readyState);
        if (http.status == 200 && http.readyState == 4) {
          alert(http.responseText);
        }
      }

      http.send();
      console.log("http request sent.");
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

With the following Apache2 configuration:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>

        Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/home/vtcakavsmoace/Documents/webpass/cert.pem"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/vtcakavsmoace/Documents/webpass/key.pem"

</VirtualHost>
```

Server B hosts a file called "file" and has the following Apache2 configuration:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>

    Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/files
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/files">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where the server expects HTTP authentication for a user called 'user' with a password 'pass'.

However, whenever someone connects to Server A, they get the following error:

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
```

Signaling that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not in the header. This is not the case, for either server. In case that this *wasn't* the issue, I have also tried curling the information through the command line, which succeeded. I have also tried changing the `http.open` line to:

```
http.open("POST", 'https://user:pass@serverb.com/file', true);
```

But this also failed.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

In case it helps, here's the output of `curl --verbose --head -u 'user:pass' https://serverb.com/file`:

```
*   Trying <redacted>...
* Connected to <redacted> (<redacted>) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 697 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: <redacted> (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: OU=<redacted>,OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15,OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R),CN=<redacted>
*    start date: Wed, 06 May 2015 13:02:37 GMT
*    expire date: Mon, 08 May 2017 08:52:24 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,O=GeoTrust Inc.,CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server auth using Basic with user '<redacted>'
> HEAD /<redacted>/file HTTP/1.1
> Host: <redacted>
> Authorization: Basic <redacted>
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2016 11:30:36 GMT
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2016 11:30:36 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Aug 2016 11:36:29 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Aug 2016 11:36:29 GMT
< ETag: "<redacted>"
ETag: "<redacted>"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 45377
Content-Length: 45377
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Content-Type: application/<redacted>
Content-Type: application/<redacted>

< 
* Connection #0 to host <redacted> left intact
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have further changed the code. The script in the webpage is now the following:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log("XML Request object created.");

http.open("POST", 'https://serverb.com/file', true);

http.withCredentials = true;

http.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '+btoa('user:pass'));

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log("readystatechange: "+http.status+":"+http.readyState);
  if (http.status == 200 && http.readyState == 4) {
    alert(http.responseText);       }
  }

http.send();
console.log("http request sent.");
```

Now, instead of simply being denied the request, I get a 401 status serverside and a 0 status client side, implying that the credentials are incorrect, even though they are correct.

**EDIT 3:**

The following edit opens up the authentication pane in Chrome, but in Firefox, a `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied` error is thrown.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log("XML Request object created.");

http.open("GET", 'https://serverb.com/file', true, 'user', 'pass');

http.withCredentials = true;

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log("readystatechange: "+http.status+":"+http.readyState);
  if (http.status == 200 && http.readyState == 4) {
    alert(http.responseText);
  }
}

http.send();
console.log("http request sent.");
```

Comment: As far as “In case that this wasn't the issue, I have also tried curling the information through the command line, which succeeded”: You understand that `curl` or any other non-browser tool will be able to access the resource regardless of whether there’s a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, right? Because `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and all other CORS headers only affect browsers, because browsers are the only applications that enforce CORS restrictions. Have you actually checked the response headers to make sure that there’s a  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker Yes, I understand that CORS is only applicable to browsers. I was verifying that the user/pass combination was working. I have checked the raw response headers and they show (on both) as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, I figured out a little bit of a workaround.

Since CORS was causing me `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied` issues, I got rid of CORS and started proxying requests forward in Apache2 configurations.

index.html final version:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      console.log("XML Request object created.");

      http.open("POST", 'file', true);

      http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log("readystatechange: "+http.status+":"+http.readyState);
        if (http.status == 200 && http.readyState == 4) {
          alert(http.responseText);
        }
      }

      http.send();
      console.log("http request sent.");
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Server A final configuration:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.c
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.c

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>

        Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/cert.pem"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/key.pem"

        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on

        # Adding a prefix for googling purposes.
        ProxyPassMatch "^/(prefix.*file.*.jpg)$" "https://serverb.com/$1"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://serverb.com/"

        <LocationMatch "^/prefix.*file.*.jpg$">

            # Pass the credentials
            AuthBasicFake "user" "pass"
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

        </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Server B final configuration:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>

    Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/files
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/files">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Another good thing about this method is that *the end user never sees the password*, so there's no authorization disclosure.